# Call a custom-written python script multiple times while hiding the console cmd window under window10

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have a python code (generate.py)that finally generated 1 line of 5 columns of data and wrote to a .csv file. I want to run it multiple times (say 1000) and write all the 1000 lines to the same csv file. I also send a str(loop_number) to the csv file so that I can trace back the data.It works fine with:

```
while(i<=1000)
    os.system('python generate.py' + ' ' + str(i))
    i +=1
```

If I try

```
subprocess.call('python generate.py' + ' ' + str(i)', shell = Ture)
```

There is no windows pop up indeed, but it also fails to write to the csv.

What should I do to run the code correctly and without cmd console pop out?

Comment: Instead of using a subprocess, you should directly import your generate.py script into the main one. You would need to either put the generate.py file next to the main script, or set your Python path so Python can find it. Then you would use and use `import generate`. No need for subprocess here :)

Comment: Could you specify what function I should use to run the script multiple times after ```import generate```? How does it add all the results for each run to the csv file?

Comment: Simply put all the code of generate.py in a function called, for example, `run`, that takes a number as argument. Now, in your main script, your code would look like this: `import generate; i = 0; while i <= 1000: generate.run(i); i += 1`

Comment: Thank you @pawamoy. You provided me a very useful suggestion. However, my generate.py is a very complicated custom-written algorithm that includes several defined functions, and it also contains some global variables. And raised different errors when i do so.  I will defiantly abandon ```os.system()```  after I adjusted it,